# How to create a unique index in PostgreSQL with subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL and try to add the index below:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_type_serial_pin_unique
ON servicestore.product_unit(serial)
WHERE serial is not null AND product_id = (SELECT id FROM servicestore.product WHERE product_type = 'SERIAL_PIN');
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in index predicate
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: So what would you expect to happen if that sub-query returns a different result tomorrow? And what if that sub-query returns more than one product (which seems quite likely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can make that work with a constraint is if you add an attribute to  `product_unit` that copies `product_type` from `product`. To make sure they are in sync, add the attribute to a foreign key from `product_unit` to `product`. Alternatively, you can use triggers to synchronize the redundant data.